# I have a problem with django-allauth linkedin signup

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-allauth

I tried to signup with the [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) linkedin module, but when the `django-allauth callback` call this URL: `/accounts/social/signup/` nothing is happening (it stuck on `/accounts/social/signup/`).

But everything is okay with the Google module of `django-allauth`.

I'm using `Django 2.2` and `django-allauth 0.39.1`.

#### My settings:

```py
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'linkedin': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'r_basicprofile',
            'r_emailaddress'
        ],
        'PROFILE_FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'first-name',
            'last-name',
            'email-address',
            'picture-url',
            'public-profile-url',
            'gender',
            'birthday'
        ],
        'HEADERS': {
            'x-li-src': 'msdk'
        }
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 1
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 10
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 86400
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'profile.CustomUSER'
```

Actually, `django-allauth` should redirect to the home page.